# Compute a column in EF Code First for insert update and delete

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, entity-framework-5

I use Entity Framework 5.0 CodeFirst approach

I have two table

```
 public class Order
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int OrderAmount { get; set; }

    public virtual IList<OrderItem> OrderItems { get; set; }
}

public class OrderItem
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int Amount { get; set; }

    public virtual Order Order { get; set; }
}
```

OrderAmount in order table is sum of amount of each orderitem
I need OrderAmount automatically calculated when i insert an order
or when i update amount of an order item

I dont push my logic to database (i dont want to use [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Computed)] and compute this value in database)

Also i know that can use

```
Public int OrderAmount{get{CalcSumOfOrderAmount()};set{}}
```

but problem is even when i want show orders in a grid CalcSumOfOrderAmount() Method run and it cuse extra loading

Is there any way to CalcSumOfOrderAmount() method run only on insert update and delete and do not run for select (in fact for select simply read date from database)?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`ObservableCollection<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668604%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
public class Order
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int OrderAmount { get; set; }

    public virtual ObservableCollection<OrderItem> OrderItems 
    { 
         get
         {
             if (orderItems == null)
             {
                 orderItems = new ObservableCollection<OrderItem>();
                 orderItems.CollectionChanged += (s, args) => 
                 {
                     OrderAmount = OrderItems.Sum(item => item.Amount);
                 }
             }
             return orderItems;
         }
    }
    private readonly ObservableCollection<OrderItem> orderItems;
}
```

Note, that I've made collection as read-only property (this is enough for materializing/saving entities and manipulating collection data). If you for some reason still need read/write `OrderItems`, than the logic will be a bit more complex, but the general idea is the same.